# setContentView makes my ImageView buttons unclickable?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

Having some trouble figuring out why my ImageView buttons stop working after I change the displayed layout in my app.  Please tell me if you see anything wrong with this code... The buttons are not clickable after changing setContentView is called even though it is setting the layout to the same one that is originally set in OnCreate. Basically I want to be able to reset the view to an known state whenever I want by calling this function.

Thanks for any ideas! Here is the code that breaks the buttons, really only the line that calls setContentView breaks the buttons, but here is the rest of the function as well:

```
    public void defaultrailview(){
      setContentView(R.layout.railtrick);
      ImageView jumpsbutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.jumpsbutton);
      ImageView settingsbutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton);
      jumpsbutton.setClickable(true);
      settingsbutton.setClickable(true);    
      ImageView ghost1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rt1);
      ghost1.setAlpha(51);
      ImageView ghost2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rt2);
      ghost2.setAlpha(51);
      ImageView ghost3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rt3);
      ghost3.setAlpha(51);
      ImageView ghost4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rt4);
      ghost4.setAlpha(51);
      ImageView railtext = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.railstext);
      railtext.setAlpha(127);
      ImageView shaketoroll = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ShakeToRoll);
      shaketoroll.setVisibility(4);
```

}

and the XML for the railtrick:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/railstext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/railstext" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alldice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dicerow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/diceghost"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/diceghost"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dicerow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rt3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/diceghost"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rt4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/diceghost"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/jumpsbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/jumpsbuttonpassive" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/railsbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/railsbuttonactive" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settingsbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/settingsbuttonpassive" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ShakeToRoll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/shaketoroll" />
```

Thanks again. Love you all!

Comment: Dude thanks for deleting your other question, i was answering it and when i finally decided to submit my answer it said u deleted it 3 minutes ago ..... you should leave all question, they don't only help you

Comment: Oh shit man, I'm so sorry. I'm new to this site, and was just super frustrated. I dunno why I deleted it... Um, I don't really know what to say, I am really sorry...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337724/buttons-in-viewpager-specifically-underneath-viewpager you can go there and click undelete only if u want to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing the same value into setContentView, you are still requesting for that resource to be inflated - meaning all new objects.

You need to reassign your onClickListeners because your old buttons are no longer on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

you can try `android:onclick="imageButton"` in the xml and create a function in your class like

```
public void imageButton(View view){
   // your code
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you think this would work versus ImageView? The buttons work fine until I call the setContentView.

Comment: in tht case, did you try to invalidate your view? or provide different names to the image views in two xmls? (I'm assuming you are setting two different views to the same activity)

Comment: Yes, 2 views for the same activity(I know this isn't great to do, but its a "for now" solution to a bigger problem that I have to give some more thought to.  Currently, I am not actually changing views, I am just re-setting the view that was initially set, so the names couldn't be different.  Also, I tried using your suggestion, and it did not work... I know that it is not recommended to change views in an activity. Can you invalidate a whole layout, or would I have to do it for each button?

Comment: Figured it out! invalidate() worked. Called jumpsbutton.invalidate() and settingsbutton.invalidate() and they are good to go! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @push.pop: Mark this answer as accepted so that other users can refer it.

Comment: I am actually going to accept the other one, as it was more effective, and the one I used. Sorry, I forgot to do this...